# Python Matplotlib - Spine coloring issue in a double-y axis plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a script to draw plot via matplotlib, the following code is an analogy to my original script that reproduce the issue that I've encountered.

```
def func(ax, data, color, position):    # A function for plotting
    ax.plot(data[0], data[1], color=color)
    ax.spines[position].set_color(color)

fig = plt.figure()
data_1 = [np.linspace(0, 1, 10), np.linspace(0, 10, 10)]
data_2 = [np.linspace(0, 1, 10), np.linspace(10, 0, 10)]

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
func(ax, data_1, 'r', 'left')

ax_1 = ax.twinx()
func(ax_1, data_2, 'b', 'right')

plt.show()
```

The expected plot should have both y axis colored, however, only right spine is colored, as shown below.
[image]

When zooming into left spine you can find a red shadow around y-axis, that means my colored spine is covered by another one, how to solve this issue by only modifying `func()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`twinx` does not only "twin" the `y` axis spine but all other three spines, too. So the red spine on the left is basically overdrawn (like you recognized already in your own answer). Instead of setting their `color` to `None`, you can `set_visible()` their visibility to `False`, which seems to be the preferred way, compared to lines 18-22 [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/d4f1f8d0b1b71c97c3f750dfa9c16c1e9ab3261b/examples/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.py).

So:

```
def func(ax, data, color, position):    # A function for plotting
    ax.plot(data[0], data[1], color=color)
    ax.spines[position].set_color(color)
    for pos in ['left', 'right']:
        if pos != position:
            ax.spines[pos].set_visible(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like other spines would be created after executing this code: `ax_1 = ax.twinx()`, so I find a "dumb" solution:

```
def func(ax, data, color, position):    # A function for plotting
    ax.plot(data[0], data[1], color=color)
    ax.spines[position].set_color(color)

    if position == 'left':
        other = 'right'
    elif position == 'right':
        other = 'left'
    ax.spines[other].set_color('None')
```

Result:

[image]

This can solve my problem, but I'm still open for other beautiful solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I am copying an answer to the question from the matplotlib documentation that could be found in the following link: https://matplotlib.org/api/spines_api.html

Here is a function that could be used:

```
def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
ax.set_frame_on(True)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)
for sp in ax.spines.values():
    sp.set_visible(False)
```

And, an example of using it in the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)


fig, host = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

par1 = host.twinx()
par2 = host.twinx()

# Offset the right spine of par2.  The ticks and label have already been
# placed on the right by twinx above.
par2.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
# Having been created by twinx, par2 has its frame off, so the line of its
# detached spine is invisible.  First, activate the frame but make the patch
# and spines invisible.
make_patch_spines_invisible(par2)
# Second, show the right spine.
par2.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], "b-", label="Density")
p2, = par1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], "r-", label="Temperature")
p3, = par2.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], "g-", label="Velocity")

host.set_xlim(0, 2)
host.set_ylim(0, 2)
par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

host.set_xlabel("Distance")
host.set_ylabel("Density")
par1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
par2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

host.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
par1.yaxis.label.set_color(p2.get_color())
par2.yaxis.label.set_color(p3.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
host.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_color(), **tkw)
par1.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p2.get_color(), **tkw)
par2.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p3.get_color(), **tkw)
host.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

lines = [p1, p2, p3]

host.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines])

plt.show()
```

Which creates the following plot:

[image: Plot multiple Y axes with different spine colors]